# PyCharm version control for local git doesn't commit

Tags: git, version-control, pycharm

I'm an absolute beginner in version control and decided to get some insights into Git. I would like to use the basic Git functionalities in PyCharm on my local computer.

So I followed [this guide](https://clt.champlain.edu/knowledgebase/configuring-git-with-pycharm/), downloaded and installed Git on my local computer. I couldn't follow step 3 ("On the top bar of PyCharm, click on VCS > Enable Version Control Integration…") because such an option isn't available on my VCS > ... menu. So I did a bit of research and found a similar option in the Settings -> Version Control where I added my project directory and selected "Git" as VCS.

Looking again at the [official guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/set-up-a-git-repository.html#put-existing-project-under-Git) I tried to add the project-folder to git, selecting VCS > Import into Version Control > Create Git Repository. There I selected my folder.

Now I'm able to open the commit menu (STR + K). But when pressing "Commit" I'm asked for a Git account. Also I'm not able to create a new branch.

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something very obvious, but most guides I find on the internet focus on either downloading or uploading the project from Git to PyCharm / PyCharm to Git...

But how can I use Git for local versioning? What did I miss during the configuration?

Comment: Maybe you should first try to use Git from the command line, to learn its basics, instead of PyCharm getting in your way additionally.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I totally agree. Please mark as solved.